# Ping every 5 seconds - Android

Tags: android, multithreading, ping

I have write this code for pinging class c ip addresses on port 6789, the thread starts when I click on a button called PING, it will retrieve all ip addresses that has the port 6789 open ... but what I need is to refresh (re-ping) every, lets say 5 seconds, and add ips recently joined if exist and omits ones that leaves the port.
I debugged and searched for it for hours but no hope !!!

Thanks in advance :DD

```
Thread pingo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (readableNetmask.equals("255.255.255.0")) {

                    for (int i = 2; i <= 254; i++) {

                        String ip_address = readableIPAddress;
                        String oct1 = "", oct2 = "", oct3 = "", oct4 = "";

                        StringTokenizer stok = new StringTokenizer(
                                ip_address, ".");

                        while (stok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            oct1 = stok.nextToken();
                            oct2 = stok.nextToken();
                            oct3 = stok.nextToken();
                            oct4 = stok.nextToken();
                        }

                        to_ping_ip = oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3 + "."
                                + String.valueOf(i);

                        if (pingAddress(to_ping_ip, 6789)) {
                            handler.post(new UpdateIPListViewRunnable());
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // ips_List.add(to_ping_ip);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        pingo.start();
```

PingAddress() Function:

```
public boolean pingAddress(String ip, int port) {

    Socket socket = new Socket();
    try {

        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 200);
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

List where addresses appear:

```
static public class UpdateIPListViewRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        arrayAdapter.add(to_ping_ip);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing in your code involving any "do it again in 5 seconds" -- making it difficult to understand what you've tried. Is your question about retrying in 5 seconds as you state, or just about getting the single ping to work? Please be more concise.

Comment: apologies for the vagueness, but i didn't mentioned that i have tried (i have searched). I have this code and it works fine for one ping per ip (1-254), but i want it to ping automatically every 5 seconds, so to be up to date which IPs are joined, leaved or still on that port ... Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Just add a loop with a 5 second sleep in it, like shown here. I suppose you can already integrate your new results of the ping into your previously captured data.

```
Thread pingo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (readableNetmask.equals("255.255.255.0")) {
                    // keep the above logic
                }

                // delay 5 seconds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    pingo.start();
```

Comment: you mean `Thread.sleep(5000)` for 5 seconds. 
Thank you very much i appreciate it ;D

Comment: mmm unfortunately another issue appears :( ... when I started the application the first iteration of the while (true) works perfectly, and it adds any ip that had the port 6789 open, and when another device joins the port, my phone will add it to the list ...... BUT in the second iteration when pinging to an ip previously pinged ... the Socket will throw  IOException (as written in the code) I don't know why :< ????

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
private void doPing() {
    if (readableNetmask.equals("255.255.255.0")) {
    // Your logic 
    }
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doPing();
        }
    }, 5*1000);
}
```

Comment: This would work however it would cause subsequent `doPing()` calls to be performed on the UI thread. It would be better if `doPing()` instead started a new thread to perform the ping logic.

Comment: In the case we don't want to do any UI stuff in `doPing()`, your logic is better. Accepted !